# how to use a function defined in another javascript file?

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, scope

well i need to call a function defined in another javascript file(file 2) in file 1.
i just wrote
in file 1

```
var ball;
var ab=document.getElementById("abcd");
funcname();
```

now in the other file(file 2)

```
function funcname()
{
    ball=ab.width; //line 2
}
```

now it shows an error like cannot find ab when it comes to line 2

i cant understand why this happens...
and i tried this and this worked

in file 1

```
 var ball;
    var ab=document.getElementById("abcd");
    funcname(ball,ab);
```

in the other file (file2)

```
function funcname(ball,ab)
    {
        ball=ab.width; //line 2
    }
```

Comment: When you call funcname() it has no idea what ab is because that is defined in a different function and is out of context. If you want access to ab in your 2nd function you must pass it as a parameter like you have

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file?rq=1

Comment: is there no other way other than using them as parameters

Answer (score 0):

In first example of File2, `ab` is undefined because you instanciated it in another file (file2 can't use variables/functions defined in file1).

In second example you pass it in parameter of the function and that's the reason why the function can use it.

And pass `ball` in parameter of the function for setting it a value after is useless !

Comment: so is there no other way than passing them as parameters( i am not talking about  ball)

Comment: You can include the file with one of the solutions given by the link of user3362707 in your first post.

Passing parameters is a problem for you ?

Comment: I just wanted to know too... You have now the solutions to solve your problem, right ?